# gRPC query waits indefinitely while execution giving no output in Seldon-Core

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, grpc

I am trying to run example from [gRPC Seldon example](https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/blob/master/notebooks/kubectl_demo_gcp.ipynb) for gRPC on google cloud kubernetes cluster. I am able to get `access_token` but gRPC query waits indefinitely. Finally I get following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_request.py", line 53, in 
grpc_request()
File "test_request.py", line 50, in grpc_request
response = stub.Predict(request=request,metadata=metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 487, in call
return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, deadline)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 437, in _end_unary_response_blocking
raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE, OS Error)>
```

Whats the issue?

Comment: How long is "indefinitely"? Seconds, minutes, or hours? How many times have you been able to reproduce the issue? Does it always fail with "OS Error"?

Comment: @NathanielManistaAtGoogle it waits about 5 mins before giving above error. It always fails with OS Error

Comment: Investigation of this problem is going to get much better in two or three weeks when [pull request 13689](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/pull/13689) is released in 1.13. :-)

Comment: @NathanielManistaAtGoogle thanks for the update!!

Comment: rishi007bansod: now that gRPC Python 1.13 is out (and has been out for a while) are you able to see more information associated with this problem?